# Intuition behind $P(B|A)P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Given that event $A$ has occured the probability that event $B$ occurs is given by $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$. From this one acquires that $P(B|A)P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)$. How does one make sense of this? I have a feeling that there's an intuitive explanation for this equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. $P(A\cap B) = P(B\cap A)$! (Of course! For events A and B to both happen is the same as for events B and A to both happen)

So, $P(B|A)P(A) = P(A\cap B) = P(B \cap A) = P(A|B)P(B)$

Comment: When you put it that way, it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This means that probability that $A$ and $B$ both happen is the same regardless $A$ happens first then $B$ happens next ($P(B|A)P(A)$), or $B$ first then $A$ next ($P(A|B)P(B)$).

Comment: +1 it was the only answer that appealed to the intuition rather than straight-up applying the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Both LHS and RHS mean the probability that event A and event B happen at the the same time, which is $P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: What is LHS and RHS?

Comment: Left hand side of the equation and right hand side